# Start working with large Lisp "library" (Calendrical Calculations)

Tags: calendar, lisp, common-lisp, astronomy

I used to write small Lisp programs, and medium programs in a derivative, Skill, by Cadence Design Systems. I now want to use the "library" of Lisp functions that comes with *Calendrical Calculations* and which can be [downloaded (for personal use) from Cambridge University](https://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/computer-science/computing-general-interest/calendrical-calculations-ultimate-edition-4th-edition?format=HB#BvCwevJdD9zJeXq7.97).

I installed the Lipstick package (which I have not worked with before) on my Windows 10 computer. (At least I've used Emacs). I've been using *Practical Common Lisp* by Peter Seibel (2005) as a text.

I want to start by giving individual function calls in the REPL, so I want to "install" the "library" in the REPL. I put the words in quotes because I'm not sure the proper Lisp words to use. I tried to just load the file and that failed, so I tried

```
(compile-file "calendar.l")
```

and the response in the REPL buffer was

```
; compiling file "c:/Users/card9/lispstick/calendar.l" (written 19 JUN 2022 01:12:02 PM):
; compiling (IN-PACKAGE "CC4")
```

The response in the other buffer, sldb[2], was

```
    The name "CC4" does not designate any package.
    [Condition of type SB-Kernel:SIMPLE-PACKAGE-ERROR]The name "CC4" does not designate any package.
    [Condition of type SB-Kernel:SIMPLE-PACKAGE-ERROR]
```

So my question is what changes should I make to the Lisp file with all the calendar functions so I can compile and load it, or alternatively, what other approach should I use to access the functions?

Comment: Is it such a good package that blows away the other libraries written in other languages that you found? Thx

Comment: @Ehvince Yes. Authors tested it for ± 10,000 years and some functions work further than that. Also, very credible in the field of calendars and astronomy. Both authors are computer science professors. Cited far and wide in the relevant fields. See [the Wikipedia article about the book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendrical_Calculations).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is both very old code and not well written.  You would probably stand more chance of making it work easily if you used a less strict compiler than SBCL: I can compile and load it in LispWorks and Clozure CL but I eventually lost the will to live when trying to make SBCL compile it.

See below for a suggested workaround which may work with SBCL.

### Something you can fix: the package problems

These are the first things you will run across, and the first version of this answer dealt only with this.  This code appears to rely on semantics for `in-package` which went away in the 1980s (specifically, it seems, [1989](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Issues/iss195_w.htm))!

The *right* fix (see below for an easier one perhaps) is to change the

```
(in-package "CC4")
...
(export ...)
```

to something like

```
(defpackage "CC4"
  (:use "CL")
  (:export ...))

(in-package "CC4")
```

Where the exported names should be turned into either strings (with the string containing the upper-cased name), or, perhaps easier, uninterned symbols (prefix name by `#:`, so `(export ... 'foo ...)` turns into `(:export ... #:foo ...)` in the `defpackage` form).

An easier fix which involves a smaller edit to the code, and is thus probably preferable, would be to place, before the `(in-package "CC4")` form, this:

```
(defpackage "CC4"
  (:use "CL"))
```

Another fix is just to predefine the package which avoids editing the file: see below.

Once you have done this you should have at least a shot at compiling the file.  If that works (there may be other problems) then you can load it and would then need to say

```
(use-package "CC4")
```

### `defconstant` problems, part one

There are a number of places where `defconstant` is used where the value of the constant depends on other functions, the first being

```
(defconstant jd-epoch
  ;; TYPE moment
  ;; Fixed time of start of the julian day number.
  (rd -1721424.5L0))
```

But the value of something defined with `defconstant` needs to be known at compile time:

> If a `defconstant` form appears as a top level form, the compiler must recognize that name names a constant variable. An implementation may choose to evaluate the value-form at compile time, load time, or both. Therefore, users must ensure that the initial-value can be evaluated at compile time (regardless of whether or not references to name appear in the file) and that it always evaluates to the same value.

And this is not the case when compiling the file.

The fix for this is either to wrap the functions called to compute the values of any `defconstant` form in a suitable `eval-when`, so

```
(defun rd (tee)
  ...)
```

Would become

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defun rd (tee)
    ...))
```

And this looks OK, but then you get this:

```
(defconstant icelandic-epoch
  ;; TYPE fixed-date
  ;; Fixed date of start of the Icelandic calendar.
  (fixed-from-gregorian (gregorian-date 1 april 19)))
```

And now `fixed-from-gregorian` and `gregorian-date` need to be wrapped in `eval-when` *as does anything they call or refer to*.

Well, other than tracing through the code to find all the functions which need to be wrapped there are two workarounds to this problem.

The first is to change the `defconstant`s to `defparameter`s and hope that nothing in the code tries to assign or otherwise muck around with the variable.  This will reduce performance but that probably does not matter.

The other is to do the traditional thing that terrible systems like this often used to require in the prehistory of CL: before you attempt to compile the system, load it interpreted.  Here is a little wrapper file which will try to do this, and which also predefines the package:

```
;;;;; Try to compile & load calendar.l
;;;

(in-package :cl-user)

;;; Define the package to avoid doom
;;;
(defpackage "CC4"
  (:use "CL"))

(let ((source (merge-pathnames (pathname "calendar.l") *load-truename*)))
  ;; Load the source, compile it and load that.
  (load source)
  (load (compile-file source)))
```

### `defconstant`s part two: order

If you look at the code you will find at line 1596 a definition of `fixed-from-icelandic` which uses `summer` free.  `summer` is defined as a constant at line 4142.  So this means that there is essentially no way that `compile-file` can do a decent job of compiling `fixed-from-icelandic`: the free variable needs to be known to be a constant before it's compiled.

This is also resolved by loading the file interpreted first however.

### `defconstant`s part three: the final collapse

This is where I gave up with SBCL.  SBCL has a very strict interpretation of [`defconstant`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defcon.htm), based I think on the clause cited above from the spec.  That means that things like

```
(defconstant foo '(1 2))
```

Are [essentially impossible in SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Defining-Constants).  There are workarounds described behind that link.

Well, that means that there's really no chance of compiling this code with SBCL because there are lots of cases like this, and still less are there chances of compiling it *after loading the interpreted version*, which we need to do.

Other CL implementations are less strict about this and will be happy.

### Giving up, and a workaround

It would probably be possible to get SBCL to compile some derivative of this code, but it would need to be *significantly* modified.  Even less fussy compilers spit out a lot of justified warnings.

However my strong suspicion is that *this code has never been compiled*.  So one workaround would be to simply not try and compile the file: modify the loader shim to be:

```
;;;;; Try to load calendar.l
;;;

(in-package :cl-user)

;;; Define the package to avoid doom
;;;
(defpackage "CC4"
  (:use "CL"))

;;; Don't even try to compile the file
(load (merge-pathnames (pathname "calendar.l") *load-truename*))
```

Doing that will let even SBCL load the file.  SBCL will spit out a lot of warnings as it compiles individual definitions, since it's a compiler-only implementation.

Whether the resulting thing will then *work* is another question, but it *will* load.

---

### A note: it's not usually this bad

This is a particularly unfortunate thing to start with: most CL code is not *anything like* as awful as this.

Comment: Thanks, I stumbled around and did something similar to your suggstions after the phrase "An easier fix". I then tried to compile the file and it got as far as the DEFCONSTANT JD-EPOCH  (which is in lower case in the file, of course) before complaining that RD was an undefined function.

Comment: @GerardAshton I've expanded the answer a lot to address some of the other problems.  Brief summary: SBCL won't compile this code and it's correct not to do so.  Some other implementations will.  You *can* load the file interpreted via a shim (which, in SBCL, means individual definitions will be compiled), and it might work.

Comment: Thanks. I did some interactive stuff on the REPL and managed to load it, call some functions, and they worked. I'm not famliar with the idea of a shim, so I took a guess. I put your code under the "Giving up, and a workaround" heading, in a file named defpackages.l and then did (load "defpackages.l") at the REPL. I got 670 lines of warnings, but the last line said "T" which I take to mean the load worked. But when I type january on the REPL I get an error message "The variable JANUARY is unbound." This worked last night. The value should have been 1.

Comment: I modified my REPL technique and it worked. First I loaded the defpackages.l file from the previous comment. Then I gave the command (in-package :CC4). Then I gave the command (fixed-from-gregorian (list 5701600 january 1)) and the program happily informed me the day count after the first 5+ million year cycle of the Gregorian calendar is 2,082,466,273 which is exactly the sort of thing I'm interested in, and which would make other calendar packages in other languages fall over dead. Marking as solution.

Comment: @GerardAshton: glad it worked.  I use 'shim' to mean 'some small thing to get from where you are to where you need to be': I don't know if that's standard usage.  You should probablt use the `CC4` package, not be in it: ince it's loaded say `(use-package "CC4")`.

Comment: Replacing `defconstant` with `defparameter` would do? (even if less safe)

Comment: @Ehvince yes (modulo the ordering problems), but I wanted to see if I could get the code to work without modifying the file.  One workaround would be to make the `CC4` package be one where `defconstant` was something else.

Comment: It will be quite a while before I try any changes beyond what I wrote 23 Jun at 12:43. The code comes with extensive sample data, but no code to run a test and compare the results to the sample data. I would want to write such a test suite before modifying the code.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, as an alternative that will work without fuss, I adapated the Common Lisp code into another Lisp dialect, Clojure: https://github.com/echeran/calendar-code2

I'm working with teammates who are implementing new calendar systems in [ICU4X](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu4x), which is written in Rust. Being able to work with the code interactively will allow them to introspect and debug their translated functions and create test cases.

The original CLisp code isn't clean, so the adapted version still needed some fixups: using Clojure's `declare` to create forward declarations to handle out-of-order `def`/`defn`s, and fixing a typo or two.